# Switching of decision variables to be equal to a certain decision variable according to a binary (indicator) variable

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints, reformulation-linearization

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following:

I have two integer decisions variables, $x, x'$, that are either equal or greater than zero and either of them is to be equated to a third integer decision variable, $z$, which is also equal or greater than zero in accordance to the value of a binary indicator variable, $\beta$.

$\beta=1$ $\implies$ $x=z$

$\beta=0$ $\implies$ $x'=z$

Appreciate your kind guidance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
x \le z + M(1-\beta) \\
x \ge z - M(1-\beta) \\
x' \le z + M\beta \\
x' \ge z - M\beta \\
$$

If $\beta=1$, we have

$$
x \le z  \\
x \ge z  \\
x' \le z + M \\
x' \ge z - M \\
$$

which leads to $x=z$ and $x'$ unconstrained. And likewise if $\beta=0$.

Comment: Dear Kuifje, thank you for your speedy answer. May I ask you in detail with regard to the case of $\beta=1$. Would last two constraints that result in an interval of integers, i.e., $z-M$$\le$$x'$$\le$$z+M$ force $x'$ to be strictly positive? For my problem zero has to be included as $x'$ is set to zero due to other constraints in the model. Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: You can add another constraint $x' \ge 0$ if you need $x'$ to be non negative no matter what. In this case $z-M \le x'$ will have no effect (if $M$ is large enough).

Comment: Dear Kuifje, pardon me for missing out on the bottom portion on $x'$ unconstrained. Could you help elaborate on the mechanism which enables it to be unconstrained as I treating it from the perspective where $z$ is a integer decision variable though which might be equal or greater than zero, it could possibly be of a certain large value that could overwhelm M causing $x'$ to not include 0. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I missed out on reading your reply when typing my 2nd question. In that case, is it correct to say that this is a compromise between selecting a large enough $M$ to ensure that $0$ is included to ensure feasibility while also making sure that it is not overly till it renders solving inefficient?

Comment: Yes that is why you have to choose $M$ big enough, in this case larger than the upper bound for $z$.

Comment: Your last comment is exact: you need $M$ large enough to prevent $z-M >0$, but not too large otherwise you might run into numerical issues.

Comment: Thank you again! Guess I have to cross my fingers that the model is solvable, and that I am able to publish and graduate cos I have lots of binary variables like this which are interconnected.

Comment: If you have more problems, I suggest you post another question with the entire model.

Comment: Not trying to sound fatalistic or am showboating, my model has close to 100 constraints and majority of them are indicator or binary constraints containing either a mix of integer decision variables and binary variables or interlinked binary variables

Comment: Sounds doable to me (this morning I [with the help of a solver that starts with G] solved a model with 400k variables, out of which 200k are binaries, and 1 million constraints)

Comment: Is the solver beginning with G better than C for such problems, i.e, laden with indicator variables and constraints, and with tightly coupled constraints rendering the application of metaheuristics and heuristics extremely challenging?

Comment: In my experience it depends on the data set, I have seen problems where G outperforms C and vice versa. Both are very powerful.

Comment: Therein lies the difficulty,